# How to handle 400 Bad request by urlopen?

Tags: python, parsing, urllib2, bad-request

I use this piece of code to generate various statistics:

```
uClient = urlopen(finalURL)
page = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
obj = json.loads(page)
return obj
```

I have a list of everything that needs to be generated, but some of those URL do not exist anymore, but the file is too big to go thourgh it by hand. Once it returns Bad request, the script runs into error, but I would like it to just pass that URL if it is a bad request and continue without existing.

Comment: try to use exception handling

Comment: Off-topic: I'd recommend changing to [`requests`](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python) module.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use exception handling

```
try:
    uClient = urlopen(finalURL)
    page = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    obj = json.loads(page)
    return obj
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    if e.code == 404:
        print "Not found"
```

Comment: What should I put in it if I sometimes get 404 Not found? ValueError doesn't seem to work for this one...

Comment: @Saeko, use [`HTTPError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError)

Comment: @t.m.adam Thank you very much! That one worked for me!

Comment: @Saeko, glad to hear that! Just keep in mind that you may have to handle other ecxeptions too (`URLError`, `ValueError`, etc)

Comment: @mkHun, no problem, but note that you may have to catch more exceptions as i mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this exception handling by @mkHun:

```
try:
   uClient = urlopen(finalURL)
   page = uClient.read()
   uClient.close()
   obj = json.loads(page)
   return obj
except ValueError:
  print "Not found"
```

but instead of using ValueError, I used urllib2.HTTPError as suggested by @t.m.adam which ultimately solved my problem. Thank you everyone!